# jQuery counter start/stop/reset not stopping correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a jQuery counter using a setInterval(), the idea is the counter should start counting once a button is pressed, and should then stop + reset to zero if another button is pressed, this process should be repeatable, however my JS doesn't appear to stop the timer even though my variables set are showing `false`. The timer should only count if it's `true`.

```js
$('.start').click(function() {
      timer(true)
    })

    $('.stop').click(function() {
      timer(false)
    })

    let timerShouldCount = false

    function timer(timerStatus) {
      timerShouldCount = timerStatus
      if (timerShouldCount == true ) {
        setInterval(function(){
          console.log('counting');
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start" type="button">Start</button>
        <button class="stop" type="button">Stop</button>
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('.js_ask-later').click(function() {
        timer(true)
      })
      $('.js_close-modal').click(function() {
        timer(false)
      })

      let registerTimer
      let timerShouldCount = false

      function timer(timerStatus) {
        timerShouldCount = timerStatus
        if (timerShouldCount == true) {
          $('#login-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            registerTimer = setInterval(function(){
              $('#login-modal').modal('show')
            }, 5000)
          })
        } else {
          clearInterval(registerTimer)
        }
      }
```

Comment: once `setInterval` has been called with a function, it will keep repeating until [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) is called with the timer ID.

Comment: There's no need to create a CodePen or a Fiddle and link to it. You can just place your code in a "snippet" when creating your question and it can be run right here.

Answer (score 2):

You're not clearing the interval at any point. For this you need a reference to the created interval.

```
let my_int;

function timer(timerStatus) {
    timerShouldCount = timerStatus
    if (timerShouldCount == true ) {
        my_int = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('counting');
        }, 1000);
    } else
        clearInterval(my_int);
}
```

---

[EDIT]

Following on from the comments below, it's apparent that you don't actually have a timer, just an interval. We need a var for the timer.

```
let my_int, timer = 0;

function timer(timerStatus) {
    timerShouldCount = timerStatus
    if (timerShouldCount == true ) {
        my_int = setInterval(function(){
            timer++; //<-- increment
            console.log('counting');
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(my_int);
        timer = 0; //<-- reset to 0
    }
}
```

What you do with that timer, i.e. where you show it in the DOM, is up to you, but you can at least see now how we increment it and reset it to 0.

Comment: Many thanks! :) Is there a way to set the timer back to zero again, or is that what `clearInterval` does?

Comment: `clearInterval()` merely kills an interval - it has nothing to do with your timer or the DOM or anything. You actually don't show a timer in your code, just an interval. Presumably you need a separate variable for the timer itself. See edit in a second...

Comment: The problem I now appear to face is that I've linked this in with a Bootstrap modal that once the modal is closed, it should reopen after 5,000 ms, but if I quickly close the modal once it's opened, the modal will close, and then will appear after what seems like 2,500, and so fourth, 1,500. It seems that the set interval speeds up? I ideally need it to start the interval from 0 when I click a Close modal button, see updated code example above.

Comment: If I dismiss my modal which clears the interval as soon as it opens, then the interval between the modal closed and reopened is correct

Comment: From your update it seems you're missing the part of my answer where I reset the timer to 0.